# Incorrect NavigationContext.QueryString values in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I got problem in creating a navigation URI on our silverlight application. I got this URI mapper:

```
<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/Dev/{id}/Cov/{isAnalysed}" MappedUri="/Views/Cov/CovListView.xaml?Id={id}&amp;isAnalysed={isAnalysed}" />
<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/Dev/{id}/Cov/{cId}/{cType}" MappedUri="/Views/Cov/CovListView.xaml?Id={id}&amp;cId={cId}&amp;cType={cType}" />
```

For the first Uri on the OnNavigatedTo method of the CovView.xaml the **NavigationContext.QueryString** would give this result.

`[0]: {[Id, 1]}`

`[1]: {[isAnalysed, true]}`

but navigating using the second URI would give this result

`[0]: {[Id, 1]}`

`[1]: {[isAnalysed, 3/DAX]}`

Not sure why it is somehow still using the first Uri.

Changing the order of the URI pattern/path (on the mapping and upon navigation) would solve the problem but for my case this should be the last option.

Has anyone meet this kind of problem and what did you do to resolve this (aside from changing the URI pattern/path)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I came out with two solutions to fix the problem.

1. Change the pattern of the URI mapper and also the caller. In which, for my case is not a good solution since there are a lot of codes already navigating to this page using these URI pattern. Changing it would change a lot of codes.
2. Second solution is that, I found out that interchanging the sequence of the URI solves the problem. Instead of the above sequence, I put the second URI mapping first.

Changed the mapping sequence to this.

```
<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/Dev/{id}/Cov/{cId}/{cType}" MappedUri="/Views/Cov/CovListView.xaml?Id={id}&amp;cId={cId}&amp;cType={cType}" />
<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/Dev/{id}/Cov/{isAnalysed}" MappedUri="/Views/Cov/CovListView.xaml?Id={id}&amp;isAnalysed={isAnalysed}" />
```

I implemented the second solution since it doesn't require me to change the pattern of the URI.

Hope this would help someone having a similar problem.